# Fire something inside a listener only if n seconds have passed since receiving last event

Tags: flutter, dart

I am listening to an event, however, I don't want to print the event every time. There is an event being sent every second but I don't want my print to work every second. How can I make the print inside this listener to fire only, if 10 seconds is past since last event?

For e.g I receive an event, I use the print. I want to store the event somewhere, if 10 seconds is passed since last event, accept another event -> print and so on.

```dart
  _controller.onLocationChanged.listen((event) {
      print(event);
    });
```

Comment: check [debounceTime](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/DebounceExtensions/debounceTime.html) - the docs say: *"Transforms a Stream so that will only emit items from the source sequence whenever the time span defined by duration passes, without the source sequence emitting another item."*

Comment: @pskink I've tried it, and Im getting this message `The method 'debounceTime' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'.`

Comment: you need to import rxdart package, https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/install

Comment: @pskink maybe you want to post it as an answer so I mark it as answered?

Comment: @pskink actually I've tried using debounceTIme and it doesn't trigger at all now

Comment: `_controller.onLocationChanged.debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 10)).listen((event) {print(event);});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something related to an asynchronous method as such. The following code will set the _isListening variable to true after 10 seconds, which will enable the listener to do it's action once again.

```
class YourClass{
    bool _isListening = true;
    
    void yourMethod() {

      _controller.onLocationChanged.listen((event) {

      if(_isListening){
        _isListening = false;
        print(event);
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10)).then((_) => _isListening=true);
      }

    });
  }
}
```

Edit: Thanks to @pskink, the proper way to do it would be by using the [debounceTime method](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/DebounceExtensions/debounceTime.html). So in proper way:

```
 _controller.onLocationChanged
    .debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 10))
    .listen((event) {
      print(event);
    });
```

Comment: this kind of stream transformer is called [debounceTime](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/DebounceExtensions/debounceTime.html) - no need in reinventing the wheel ;-)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the information. Never really found that one - I'll edit my answer, to match your response.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Timer like below:

```
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 10), (){
      print("...");
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it prints every second